# Data usage slider missing in Android Lollipop

Tags: mobile-data

After upgrading my Galaxy S5 to Android 5.0, the sliding bar on the graph which allows you to show data usage for a prescribed date range is no longer there. For example, in the older Android I was able to slide the bar to show data usage for the last 24 hours, or for whatever range of days I wanted- it was so easy and fast. I understand that there is an option to change the date range in the options, but this is more time consuming and you need to change it every time you want to show a different range- the slider was so much easier and faster. Is there any way to bring this back or perhaps an app that has this feature? I don't understand why several useful features have been removed in the new update, as I mention in my other question here.

Comment: It's a Lollipop thing and not Samsung specific. A lot of people are pretty unhappy about it. I haven't come across the reason why the previous usage sliders were removed.

Comment: Yea I always miss those sliders. They were so useful for tracking down data hogger apps! Sometimes Google just decides to kill something that is very useful because they think they know better. What is that option to change date range (the one you mentioned as time consuming)? Is it to change start date of cycle? I find that changing start date is a workaround to filter the data usage at least for the last x days.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung probably removed this ability in their recent update, as LG handsets are also missing this feature from previous Android versions.  The best course of action to monitor your data usage in detail is to run a search on the Play Store for data monitoring apps.  [A quick search I ran returns a plethora of results.](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=data%20monitoring&c=apps)

Answer (score 0):

Thing is mine disappeared but I still got the notification that I reach my limit. From that notification I could use the data slider but if I come out from it I won't be able to get it unless the notification comes up again.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if it'll work, but disable wi-fi, enable mobile data and resart your phone, try if it works

Comment: Nope that doesn't work- that option seems to have completely gone- there is no sliding bar at all. Does anyone know if it was removed or whether there might be an app that has this feature?